# D3 bind data for exiting

Tags: data-binding, d3.js, transition

In this jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/3NUJE/3/), I'm changing the data key bound to an object by passing a different string:

```
// Create rectangles
var rects = chart
    .selectAll('rect') 
    .data(data, function(d) {return d + 'a'}) 
    ...

// Update data -- all should be removed
d3.selectAll('rect')
    .data([5,6], function(d) { return(d + 'b'); })
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .delay(2000)
    .remove();
```

Unfortunately, these are bound to the same key (ie, 5 and 6 don't get removed)-- is it possible to differentiate them without changing the data array that I pass?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do. Which elements do you want to match the new data to, i.e. which `rect`s should be kept and which removed?

Comment: In this case, all elements should be removed because the key includes the string 'b', not 'a'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key function that you can pass to `.data()` is executed for both the new data elements and the ones that are bound already. That is, when you bind data and use a key function, the key returned by that function isn't stored with the data. This means that it doesn't matter what you change the key function to for your second call, as long as the actual data is the only thing that changes the new data will match existing data.

For example for data element `5` the key function returns `5b`. For the data already bound to the elements it returns `1b`, `4b`, `5b`, etc. The two `5b` match.

You could pass objects with more attributes instead of numbers and then use another attribute (which would have to be different for the new data) as a key.

Comment: Thanks much -- I guess that's obvious, but I had never encountered this issue before.